# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyzabbix'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, zabbix

`pyzabbix` is a module needed for this script to work. I installed it using pip, please see a confirmation below:

```
  WARNING: The script chardetect.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\Christopher Ezimoha\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed certifi-2019.11.28 chardet-3.0.4 idna-2.8 pyzabbix-0.7.5 requests-2.22.0 urllib3-1.25.8
C:\Users\Christopher Ezimoha\Desktop>
```

However, I'm getting an error at line 24 that the module can't be found. I'm not sure what I need to do.
Please see the script below and advise accordingly as I need this code to read a CSV file and update an application called `Zabbix`.

```
def addHosts(zapi):
    # Add Hosts

    file = open('hosts.csv', 'r')
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    devicelist = list(reader)
    import csv

    def login():
        # Login/authenticate below
        session = ZabbixAPI('https://zabbix.xxxxxx.xxx')
        # session = ZabbixAPI('http://xxxxxxxxxx/zabbix')
        session.login(user="xxxxxxxxxxxx", password="xxxxxxxx")
        print("Connected to Zabbix API Version %s" % session.api_version())
        return session

    for row in devicelist:
        device = row[0]
        hostgroup = row[1]
        responsegroup = zapi.hostgroup.get(filter={'name': hostgroup})
        groupid = responsegroup[0]['groupid']
        ip = row[2]
        templatePriority = row[3]
        responsepriority = zapi.template.get(filter={'name': templatePriority})
        templatePriorityId = responsepriority[0]['templateid']
#        if templatePriority == 'P1':
#            templatePriorityId = '40874'
        templateType = row[4]
        responsetype = zapi.template.get(filter={'name': templateType})
        templateTypeId = responsetype[0]['templateid']
        try:
            response = zapi.host.create(
                host=device,
                interfaces=[{
                    'type': 2,
                    'main': 1,
                    'ip': ip,
                    'dns': '',
                    'port': 161,
                    'useip': 1
                }],
                groups=[{
                    'groupid': groupid}],
                templates=[{'templateid': templatePriorityId}, {'templateid': templateTypeId}],
                inventory_mode=1
            )

            print("Created new host: " + device)
        except ZabbixAPIException as e:
            if 'already exists' in e[0]:
                print("Already created host " + device)
            else:
                print(e[0])
    return


def main():
    #    hostgroup = raw_input('Hostgroup: ')
    #hostgroup = "ALTC - Altcar"
    zapi = login()
    addHosts(zapi)
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have both python 2 and 3 installed? If you have both, `pip` installs modules under `python2`. Try installing like this if you'd like the module to be installed under `python3`:

```
pip3 install pyzabbix
```

Comment: Hi Emrah, thanks for your comment. I have Python 3.7 and 3.8 installed. In this case, how do I tell Pip to install pyzabbix on Python 3.7?

Comment: I think you should have `pip3.7` and `pip3.8` installed on your system. Try using `pip3.7 install pyzabbix`

Comment: I have tried it and this is what I got "C:\Users\Christopher Ezimoha>pip3.7 install pyzabbix
Requirement already satisfied: pyzabbix in c:\users\christopher ezimoha\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python37\site-packages (0.7.5)"

Comment: hmm ok, the next thing to verify is that you are using python3.7 exe to run your python code.

Comment: I have checked, the Python interpreter I'm using to run the program is 3.7

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no `import`, in the code you included in the question:

```
from pyzabbix import ZabbixAPI
```

2. The `login()` function should be defined outside of `addHosts()`, in order to be called like that in `main()`

Comment: Hi Iron, thanks for your comment, I have added the import.  "from pyzabbix import ZabbixAPI, ZabbixAPIException"

Comment: Can you please explain more as I'm quite new to python. I have declared the login() outside the addHost and I got more errors.

Comment: Just tried again. I'm still getting same error. '''Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Christopher Ezimoha/PycharmProjects/untitled/Test.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pyzabbix import ZabbixAPI, ZabbixAPIException
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyzabbix''''

Comment: i tried it and it does work, see https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/0217e4d3-b803-41b5-ab93-5774a60215df/?i=true

Comment: I just tried it and still getting the same error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Christopher Ezimoha/PycharmProjects/untitled/zabbiximport.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyzabbix import ZabbixAPI
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyzabbix'"

Comment: Is there something I need to adjust on the platform I'm using?

Comment: are you using a virtual environment perhaps?

Comment: No, I'm using my window machine. I was wondering if I have to declare the path of where the module is on my system?